# How to shutdown the computer after closing the powershell window?

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell. I have a powershell script I've been using to backup my files. After it runs, I would like to shutdown the computer and close the powershell window. It seems I can do one or the other, but not both. So when I restart the computer, powershell complains that it was not closed properly.

How to shutdown the computer after closing the powershell window?

TIA

p.s. Contrary to popular belief, I have read the manual. However, as mentioned below, if I put EXIT before Stop-Computer, the script exits before executing Stop-Computer. If I put EXIT after Stop-Computer, powershell complains that the file was not closed properly on reboot. Either way, I lose. :(

Comment: We all are new to things and need help. Always default to the built-in help files on any product first, for guidance and examples.

As we all know, shutting down the computer, auto closed any running app, services, etc. Restarting a Windows computer, will try and pick back up where you left off, where it can.  If that is not what you are after, [then force close the script process](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-exit/) before restarting/stopping the system.

Comment: I did test it (as I don't want to restart now) but maybe something like: `Start-Process PowerShell 'Stop-Computer'; Exit`

Comment: @postanote If I put Exit before Stop-Computer, the script exits without shutting down the computer. If I put Exit after Stop_Computer, powershell complains that the ps1 script was not properly closed on reboot--either way, I lose :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell does provid and 'Exit', as noted in my comment. As for stopping, just put the 'Stop-Computer' cmdlet at the end of your script to shut down the computer.

```
Get-Help -Name Stop-Computer -examples
# Results
<#
NAME
    Stop-Computer

SYNOPSIS
    Stops (shuts down) local and remote computers.


    ----------- Example 1: Shut down the local computer -----------

    Stop-Computer -ComputerName localhost


    Example 2: Shut down two remote computers and the local computer

    Stop-Computer -ComputerName "Server01", "Server02", "localhost"

    `Stop-Computer` uses the ComputerName parameter to specify two remote computers and the local computer. Each computer is shut down.
    -- Example 3: Shut down remote computers as a background job --

    $j = Stop-Computer -ComputerName "Server01", "Server02" -AsJob
    $results = $j | Receive-Job
    $results

    `Stop-Computer` uses the ComputerName parameter to specify two remote computers. The AsJob parameter runs the command as a background job. The job objects are stored in the `$j` variable.

    The job objects in the `$j` variable are sent down the pipeline to `Receive-Job`, which gets the job results. The objects are stored in the `$results` variable. The `$results` variable displays the job information
    in the PowerShell console.

    Because AsJob creates the job on the local computer and automatically returns the results to the local computer, you can run `Receive-Job` as a local command.
    ------------ Example 4: Shut down a remote computer ------------

    Stop-Computer -ComputerName "Server01" -Impersonation Anonymous -DcomAuthentication PacketIntegrity

    `Stop-Computer` uses the ComputerName parameter to specify the remote computer. The Impersonation parameter specifies a customized impersonation and the DcomAuthentication parameter specifies authentication-level
    settings.
    ---------- Example 5: Shut down computers in a domain ----------

    $s = Get-Content -Path ./Domain01.txt
    $c = Get-Credential -Credential Domain01\Admin01
    Stop-Computer -ComputerName $s -Force -ThrottleLimit 10 -Credential $c

    `Get-Content` uses the Path parameter to get a file in the current directory with the list of domain computers. The objects are stored in the `$s` variable.

    `Get-Credential` uses the Credential parameter to specify the credentials of a domain administrator. The credentials are stored in the `$c` variable.

    `Stop-Computer` shuts down the computers specified with the ComputerName parameter's list of computers in the `$s` variable. The Force parameter forces an immediate shutdown. The ThrottleLimit parameter limits the
    command to 10 concurrent connections. The Credential parameter submits the credentials saved in the `$c` variable.
#>
```

Or use the ***Restart-Computer*** cmdlet, if that is your goal instead.

***Update***

Use two scripts, main and child.

```
# Start-Main.ps1
0..4 | 
ForEach{
    "Inside function... $PSItem"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
.\Start-Child
Exit


# Start-Child.ps1
'Preparing to shutdown in 10 seconds'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
Stop-Computer
```

or Using PS Jobs is another option as noted in my comment:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: If I put EXIT before Stop-Computer, the script exits without stopping the computer. If I put EXIT after Stop_computer, Powershell complains that the ps1 script was not properly closed--either way I lose :(

Comment: You do not say how you are calling this script. Meaning in the ISE/Consolehost/VSCode. Anyway, you can use a dirty workaround, by using 2 scripts. Your main script just before you exit calls the child that has a wait/delay associated with it. Of course, set a delay before the exit to allow the child to start. This will allow your main script to exit and whatever delay you place in the child script will do its thing. Of course, the child only has two commands in it: Start-Sleep -Second 3 and Stop-Computer; or run them as PS jobs. See the Start-Job cmdlet details, where job2 monitors job1.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. I run the script in Debug mode in the Windows Powershell ISE window. The commands are placed without a sleep between them, each on their own line. Is that my error?  Thanks.

Comment: No worries, things happen. remember scripts process really fast, and if you have a script flow/dependencies, then you need to control that. What I am showing is just a quick and dirty (Q&D) simple way of testing out what you are after.

Comment: the dot '.\' means the current path. If it is not there then you have to fully qualify the path to any .ps1/file, etc you'd want to run.

Comment: with further testing, the above scripts still are not closing the power shell ise correctly before shutting down the computer. Help please.

Comment: related question, will a job started with start-job terminate when the main power shell session ends? If so, should I use start-process?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Based on your comment 'with further testing, the above scripts still are not closing the power shell ISE correctly before shutting down the computer'. I am not sure what you mean by this, and that is not an issue on my system, using the console/ISE/VSCode. Sure you can run code from the ISE, but it's really a development environment, not an automation run environment. Sure it can, but, make your life easy, just use the console. As for not closing the ISE correctly, if you have other stuff up in the ISE, then, that's an issue, because the ISE needs to be told what to do with that.

Comment: Sure you can use Start-Process to run scripts from the ISE, I do that all the time (meaning, shelling out to powershell.exe or pwsh.exe as needed - or the like.), but not for the shutdown of the system stuff. I can't imagine why one would shut down their system from a development environment, but hey, we all have our reasons. You have to chain jobs, just as you would chain script. [The main job starts. a child job in waiting for a response before it does its thing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_job_details?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and direction with this. So much to learn. Having come from simple cmd bat files, I lacked the overall concepts used in PS…When I say “not closing down correctly”, when I restart the ise, it tells me that the file was not closed and asks to reopen it. As to why I would shutdown from the ise, I was trying to get the script to behave the same from both the console and the ise-apparently a dumb idea.   :)

Comment: No worries. We are here to help when and where we can. This ISE is a tool I've used since its release and still do today. Yet, know the console in the ISE is not an actual console. It's an output window with console capabilities. The ISE like any browser, if you have tabs open, and restart/stop and reboot your system and restart your browser, it will ask you if you want to restore that session. Many MS products o this; for example, all of MSOffice, VSCode, and as you discovered the ISE. So, sure, you can use the ISE like the console, but not completely. It has its limitations and advantages.